# Why in the pumping lemma of a context free grammar $|vy| > 0$ and $|vxy| ≤ p$?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Let us consider the case where $p > 0$ exists and a string $|w| ≥ p$ can be divided into $uv^{i}xy^{i}z$ for each $i ≥ 0$.

When we say that

$|vy| > 0$ do we mean that at least one of the two must be greater than zero? or both? is it possible to demonstrate this condition with a practical example?

Similarly why $|vxy| <= p$? Is it possible to have a demonstration and practical example for this too?